# + symbol within cookie value replaced by whitespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a cookie with a `+` symbol. The value of the cookie is something like `+33123456789`. From my controller, if I do `cookies[:phoneNumber]`, it returns `33123456789` (note the whitespace before `3`).

I could replace the whitespace with a `+` but the value is correct within the cookie so I prefer to find a way to directly recover the good value of the cookie.

Why does rails removes the + symbol and how to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: How are you assigning to the cookie? It should be [URL-escaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) as `%2b` for you automatically, and decoded when accessing `cookies`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a cookie with a `+` symbol […] the value is correct within the cookie

In a HTTP request / response, a `+` in a cookie value has special meaning: it represent a space.

The server sets cookies via a HTTP header:

```
Set-Cookie: NAME=VALUE
```

The client sends them back in a similar way:

```
Cookie: NAME=VALUE
```

According to the [spec](https://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html) the `NAME=VALUE` sequence must not contain semi-colon, comma and white space. To add those characters, they must be encoded. The encoding will typically be [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) which maps the 3 excluded characters to:

```
require 'rack/utils'

Rack::Utils.escape(';') #=> "%3B"
Rack::Utils.escape(',') #=> "%2C"
Rack::Utils.escape(' ') #=> "+"
```

So if your controller turns a literal `+` into space, it works as expected:

```
Rack::Utils.unescape('+33123456789')
#=> " 33123456789"
```

To correctly represent a `+`, it has to be sent as `%2B`:

```
Rack::Utils.escape('+33123456789')
#=> "%2B33123456789"
```

Decoding such value will give the expected result:

```
Rack::Utils.unescape('%2B33123456789')
#=> "+33123456789"
```

Note that Rails handles the escaping / unescaping automatically when accessing the cookies via `ActionController#cookies`.

Maybe you set the cookie manually or outside of the `cookies` helper. Or (quite unlikely) the client isn't encoding the cookie correctly.